# Не удается запустить Tomcat

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, netbeans

Не удается запустить. Сначало вышло что порт занят заменила. Теперь так выходит с терминала не получается запустить не находит файл.

> Не удалось запустить Tomcat, проверьте возможность выполнения /Users/aiamirzakul/Downloads/apache-tomcat-7.0-2.82/bin/catalina.sh и соответствующих сценариев.
>   /Users/aiamirzakul/NetBeansProjects/WebApplication3/nbproject/build-impl.xml:1045: Ошибка при развертывании: Не удалось запустить Tomcat, проверьте возможность выполнения /Users/aiamirzakul/Downloads/apache-tomcat-7.0-2.82/bin/catalina.sh и соответствующих сценариев.
>   Для получения подробных сведений см. протокол сервера.

Comment: Для получения подробных сведений см. протокол сервера. - посмотрите и приложите логи запуска. А пока "Не удалось запустить Tomcat"

Answer (score 0):

Сервис-->Параметры-->Настройки прокси
Выбираете пункт "без прокси"
Применить
Дальше